# Drawing an UIImage as a subview of MKMapView puts less strain on the CPU compared to drawing it as annotation within the mapview. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa

While moving a few images around, within a map view, I discovered that wrapping the images into an Annotation -- then moving that annotation around, was causing heavy utilization of the CPU.

After an alternative approach was taken, wrapping the images into UIImageView and adding the image view as a subview to MKMapViews' view, the "moving around the image" could be done with almost 0% CPU usage.

Why? My initial assumption is that subviews are drawn using the GPU but I cannot find any documentation to back up my assumption.

Attached are screenshots from instruments. The blue part of the first image represents the cpu usage when taking the annotation approach.
[image: High Cpu Usage]
The Blue part of the second image shows the cpu usage when taking the UIImageView-as-subview approach.
[image: Low Cpu Usage]

The two UML diagrams represent the design of each approach.

Annotation Design
[image: first design]

Subview Design
[image: second design]

Finally, here is the code used for the subview approach.
Unfortunately the code for the Annotation approach has been lost.

```
#pragma mark - Zombie Drawing

/** Draws the zombies found in self.zombiesCoordinates onto the map.
 *  @remark Not the most efficient code but it is very readable. Uses less than 1% cpu on iPhone 4s.
 */
 - (void) displayZombiesOnMap {
// 1. Ensure the zombies have a pairing uiimageview, if not create one.
// 2. Detect if zombie has been deleted, then remove his uiimageview.
// 3. Redraw at correct coordinates.

NSAssert(_mapView != nil, @"Map was nil!");
NSAssert(self.zombiesCoordinates != nil, @"zombieCoordinates dictionary was nil");
#ifdef DEBUG
if (self.zombiesCoordinates.count == 0) {
NSLog(@"%@ : Warning, dictionary empty", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
#endif
// 1.
// Handle deletion of zombies, by removing UIImageViews which do not belong to any zombie identifier.
for (UIImageView * view in _mapView.subviews) {
  NSNumber *tagOfView =[NSNumber numberWithInteger:view.tag];
  CLLocation *coordinates =[self.zombiesCoordinates objectForKey:tagOfView];
// Map can have multiple subviews. Only concern those of UIImageView class as its used to draw the images.
  if (coordinates == nil &&[view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
}

// 2.
// Create a new UIImageView for new zombies, add it to the map.
NSEnumerator *zombiesKeyEnumerator = self.zombiesCoordinates.keyEnumerator;
id key;
while ((key = zombiesKeyEnumerator.nextObject)) {
BOOL zombieHasAView = FALSE;
NSInteger zombieID =[key integerValue];
for (UIImageView * view in _mapView.subviews) {
    if (view.tag == zombieID) {
    zombieHasAView = YES;
    break;
    }
}

// Create a UIImageView if one does not excist for the current zombie.
if (!zombieHasAView) {
    // Convert the zombies GPS coordinates into coordinates within the MapView.
  CLLocation *geoCoords =[self.zombiesCoordinates objectForKey:key];
    NSAssert(geoCoords != nil, @"geoCoords are nil!");

    // Create the zombie view
    UIImage *zombieImage = IMAGE_ZOMBIE NSAssert(zombieImage != nil, @"Image not found!");
  UIImageView *view =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:zombieImage];
    view.tag = zombieID;

  CGPoint pointInMapView =[_mapView convertCoordinate: geoCoords.coordinate toPointToView:_mapView];
    centerViewAtPoint(view, pointInMapView);

  [_mapView addSubview:view];
}
}

// 3.
// Move views to new locations, to match the new location of zombies.
for (UIImageView * view in _mapView.subviews) {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
  NSNumber *zombieID =[NSNumber numberWithInteger:view.tag];
    NSAssert(zombieID != nil, @"zombieID is nil");

  CLLocation *geoCoords =[self.zombiesCoordinates objectForKey:zombieID];
    NSAssert(geoCoords != nil, @"geoCoords are nil!");

  CGPoint pointInMapView =[_mapView convertCoordinate: geoCoords.coordinate toPointToView:_mapView];
    centerViewAtPoint(view, pointInMapView);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViews use a Core Animation CALayer as their backing, and that is indeed drawn using the GPU.  I’m not familiar with MapKit, but most likely an Annotation is rendered as part of the map tile(s) it covers, which means when you move it the system will have to re-draw the affected map tiles.